# handle undo and redo in org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have created a field(multiline text box) in my preference page, which extends org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditor. In the field i need to handle Ctrl+Z - undo  and Ctrl+R - redo. I tried to use the below code in the setText method. This does not do the job....please suggest how i need to preoceed.

```
MyViewer            myViewerField;  //my SourceViewer class

public void setText(final String txt) {

    this.myViewerField.setDocument(new Document(txt));
    final IUndoManager undoManager = new TextViewerUndoManager(25);
    undoManager.connect(this.myViewerField);
    this.myViewerField.setUndoManager(undoManager); //new     TextViewerUndoManager(10));
}
```

Comment: You might be able to work it out from the source of `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.actions.ExpressionInputDialog` which is the only thing I can find that does this.

Comment: so there is no way to do undo operation in org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditor?

Comment: It may be possible but it requires a lot of research to see exactly what is required.